# Accessing conda environment variable from python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Im trying to access $CONDA_PREFIX environment variable from Python but I get empty string always and if I use "$" it throws exception

```
import os
os.path.join(os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'], "/mypath")
```

However I find the variable from my terminal (`echo $CONDA_PREFIX`). How to access this value from Python Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "/" from the second variable. os.path.join adds by himself (as per necessity).

```
import os
os.path.join(os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'], "mypath")
```

Output

```
'<condaprefix>/mypath'
```

As per the documentation, if you enter like this (with "/")

```
os.path.join(os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'], "/mypath")
```

since "/mypath" is absolute path, it discards all the paths before it, which is conda_prefix here. So you don't need to specify absolute path.

Comment: No, my question is os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] is always None so how to access this variable

Comment: conda_prefix = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX']. If you have activated the conda environment, then make sure that you are running the python which comes with this conda environment. So if you using linux terminal, then run python script from the same terminal where you activated this conda environment.